# Kafka Multiple Consumers and Latency

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to have multiple consumers subscribed to a topic with a number of partitions equal to the number of consumers.

I would like to ask if the latency of reading those messages from the partitions is increased  linearly with the number of consumers (and partitions, since I have the same number of partitions and consumers) or non-linearly?

Answer (score 1):

Since only one consumer thread can be assigned to one partition at a time, then the total sum of all partition lags should go down faster if you have one dedicated consumer thread/application per partition.

The latency of processing the messages should also be lower because each consumer isn't trying to rebalance over more than one partition

Comment: The documentation of Kafka, https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theconsumer, declares :  "If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes." In this case the relationship latency-number_of_consumer_groups is it linear or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have different *consumer groups*, then having the same number of groups as partitions doesn't really offer any benefits, and it might introduce some lag, but mostly at the network level, not just from the Kafka API. The brokers will try to prefetch messages and load them in the page cache for fast access at the server-side. I doubt it's linear, though, until up to a point where you've saturated the network

Comment: I have not understood how true broadcast is achieved. Is it achieved when all the consumer instances have different consumer groups and one partition? In this case the increase of number of different groups triggers a  non-linear  increaseof latency? Or is it completely distributed?

Comment: More consumers in general of different groups cause an increase in read times, but it's less than linear, mostly because of the page cache holding the data that's being read. I have not personally ran any types of performance testing to say how much it is affected... The part of the documentation you quoted is simply a fact of any pubsub system; any subscriber to a channel/topic is going to receive each message its interested in. Not sure I understand what you mean by "true broadcast", but each unique group coordinates itself and polls those records from the partition leaders